# Multiple language error messages in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization

we are creating international versions of our online store and i have been tasked with the job of untangling all the javascript error messages, so they appear in the relevant language on that site.

What i obviously want to do is keep the same set of javascript for all the sites, but just load in a set of error messages from a german/french/italian language text file for example. I thought that this might be possible to do with separate json files that just hold a set of plain text error messages.

Can anyone suggest the easiest and most scalable solution to this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul, if you're going to insist on those tags, how about making sure they're on questions that are actually about the relevant standards?

Answer (score 7):

One option you have is to create Javascript language files and include the right one right before your Javascript file. On the server-side, the selected language is known, so the right file can easily be included. In the language file, you define variables that can be used in your code.

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lang_en.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourjavascript.js" />
```

`lang_en.js` can be either `lang_de.js` or anything, the server decides.

In the language files you have something like (simplified, global stuff, just want to show the idea):

```
var lang = {
    ARE_YOU_SURE : 'Are you sure?',
    ...
};
```

And in your main Javascript file you can simply do:

```
alert(lang.ARE_YOU_SURE);
```

Comment: Simples solution! I like it, it was the best fit for my code. The only difference is that i used a json file instead of js.

Answer (score 1):

i have kind of solved my issue of how to retrieve the messages and pass in variables of my own as well. Here is the code to a simple test page i have built:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.topshop.com/javascript/wearwiths/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="brand.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var msg, xVal = 2, yVal = 8, prodName = "Blue Skirt", msg_type = "information", lang = "eng";

            $.ajax({
                url: lang + '_messages.js',
                dataType: 'script',
                scriptCharset: 'utf-8',
                success: function() {
                    console.log("The " + lang + " language file was loaded.");
                    msg = messages || {};
                }
            });

            function translate(message, details) {

                if(message.indexOf("{currency}") != -1) {
                    message = message.replace("{currency}", Arcadia.Brand.currency);
                    console.log(typeof Arcadia.Brand.currency);
                }

                if(message.indexOf("{val}") == -1) {
                    return message;
                } else {                    
                     for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
                        message = message.replace("{val}", details[i]);
                     }                                                      
                    return message;                             
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var listItem, listIndex;
                $('#item_list li a').click(function() {

                    listItem = $(this).parent();
                    listIndex = $('ul#item_list li').index(listItem);
                    toString(listIndex);

                    switch (msg_type) {
                        case "information":
                            $("p#error").text(translate(msg.information["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            console.log(translate(msg.information["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            break;

                        case "product_or_bundle":
                            $("p#error").text(translate(msg.product_or_bundle["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            console.log(translate(msg.product_or_bundle["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            break;

                        case "error":
                            $("p#error").text(translate(msg.error["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            console.log(translate(msg.error["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            break;

                        case "code":
                            $("p#error").text(translate(msg.code["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            console.log(translate(msg.code["mes_" + listIndex], [xVal, "14"]));
                            break;
                    }                   
                    return false;
                });

                $('ul#message_select li a').click(function() {
                    msg_type = $(this).attr('href');
                    msg_type = msg_type.replace('#', "");                                       
                });

                $('select#lang').change(function () {
                    lang = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: lang + '_messages.js',
                        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'script',
                        success: function() {
                            console.log("The " + lang + " language file was loaded.");
                            msg = messages || {};
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            p {
                background: green;
                color: #fff;
            }

            p span {
                background: darkblue;
            }

            em {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-style: normal;
                color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>V7 site messaging test</h1>
        <h2>Select message language</h2>
        <form>
            <select id="lang">
                <option value="eng" title="Switch the language to English">English</option>
                <option value="fra" title="Switch the language to French">French</option>
                <option value="ger" title="Switch the language to German">German</option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <h2>Select message type</h2>
        <ul id="message_select">
            <li><a href="#information" title="Information">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#product_or_bundle" title="Product or Bundle">Product or Bundle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#error" title="Error">Error</a></li>
            <li><a href="#code" title="Code">Code</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <ul id="item_list">
            <li><a href="#" title="list item 1">list item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 14</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 15</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 16</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 17</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 18</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 19</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 20</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">list item 22</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p id="error">Error Message will appear here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue i am now having is that the foreign laguage characters for French and German are coming out as nonsense. It is something to do with character sets, but i have set the charset to utf-8 in the html and the ajax call, to the js messages file specifies using the utf-8 charset. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Just for completeness sake here is my English laguage messages in the file eng_messages.js:

```
var messages = {
"information":  {
                        "mes_0": "this link will open in a new browser window",
                        "mes_1": "This link will open in a new browser window",
                        "mes_2": "Rollover image from left to right to rotate",
                        "mes_3": "Loading tweets...",
                        "mes_4": "Latest Tweets",
                        "mes_5": "Click to view photo {val}",
                        "mes_6": "Click to view 360",
                        "mes_7": "Click to view video",
                        "mes_8": "Click to view photo",
                        "mes_9": "out of stock",
                        "mes_10": "low stock",
                        "mes_11": "click on a size below",
                        "mes_12": "Sorry, this item is out of stock.",
                        "mes_13": "Select Size: ",
                        "mes_14": "Please wait",
                        "mes_15": "Continue shopping",
                        "mes_16": "{val} item(s) added to bag",
                        "mes_17": "Size {val}",
                        "mes_18": "{val} item(s) in your bag Subtotal: {currency}{val}",
                        "mes_19": "s",
                        "mes_20": "item",
                        "mes_21": "You need to select a size before you can add this item to your bag."
                        },
"product_or_bundle":    {
                        "mes_0": "Rollover image to zoom.",
                        "mes_1": "View large image",
                        "mes_2": "Photo {val} of prod name",
                        "mes_3": "Scroll up",
                        "mes_4": "Scroll down",
                        "mes_5": "View details of {val}",
                        "mes_6": "Remove this item",
                        "mes_7": "Remove",
                        "mes_8": "Scroll left",
                        "mes_9": "Scroll right",
                        "mes_10": "Check Availability In Store:",
                        "mes_11": "Outfit added to bag",
                        "mes_12": "Click to view full details of this item"
                        },
"error":                {
                        "mes_0": "Sorry, an error occurred when trying to add your item. Please try again.",
                        "mes_1": "Sorry, an error occurred when trying to add your items. Please try again.",
                        "mes_2": "You need to select a size for each item before you can add the outfit to your bag."
                        },
"code":                 {
                        "mes_0": "[View your bag] [Go to checkout] continue shopping button",
                        "mes_1": "[View your bag]  [Go to checkout]"                        
                        }
}
```

and here are the German messages in a file called ger_messages.js:

```
var messages = {
"information":  {
                        "mes_0": "Dieser Link wird in einem neuen Fenster öffnen",
                        "mes_1": "Dieser Link wird in einem neuen Browser-Fenster geöffnet",
                        "mes_2": "Rollover-Bild von links nach rechts zu drehen",
                        "mes_3": "Loading tweets...",
                        "mes_4": "Aktuelle Tweets",
                        "mes_5": "Klicken Sie auf ein Foto, Blick {val}",
                        "mes_6": "Klicken Sie auf 360 Ansicht",
                        "mes_7": "Klicken Sie, um Video anzusehen",
                        "mes_8": "Klicken Sie auf ein Foto, Blick",
                        "mes_9": "ausverkauft",
                        "mes_10": "Wenige Exemplare auf Lager",
                        "mes_11": "Klicken Sie auf eine Größe unterhalb",
                        "mes_12": "Leider ist der Artikel nicht auf Lager.",
                        "mes_13": "Wählen Sie Größe:",
                        "mes_14": "Bitte warten",
                        "mes_15": "Einkauf fortsetzen",
                        "mes_16": "{val} Artikel hinzugefügt Tasche",
                        "mes_17": "Größe {val}",
                        "mes_18": "{val} Artikel hinzugefügt Tasche Zwischensumme: £{val}",
                        "mes_19": "s",
                        "mes_20": "artikel",
                        "mes_21": "Sie müssen eine Größe auswählen, bevor Sie diesen Artikel in Ihre Tasche hinzufügen können."
                        },
"product_or_bundle":    {
                        "mes_0": "Rollover-Bild zu vergrößern.",
                        "mes_1": "Bild vergrößern",
                        "mes_2": "Foto {val} von {val}",
                        "mes_3": "Blättern Sie nach oben",
                        "mes_4": "Blättern Sie nach unten",
                        "mes_5": "Detailansicht der {val}",
                        "mes_6": "Diesen Artikel entfernen",
                        "mes_7": "Entfernen",
                        "mes_8": "Blättern Sie nach links",
                        "mes_9": "Blättern Sie nach rechts",
                        "mes_10": "Überprüfen Sie die Verfügbarkeit im Shop:",
                        "mes_11": "Outfit hinzugefügt Tasche",
                        "mes_12": "Hier klicken vollständigen Details zu diesem Element anzuzeigen"
                        },
"error":                {
                        "mes_0": "Leider trat ein Fehler beim Versuch, Ihren Artikel hinzuzufügen. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.",
                        "mes_1": "Leider trat ein Fehler beim Versuch, Ihre Elemente hinzuzufügen. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.",
                        "mes_2": "Sie müssen eine Größe für jeden Artikel, bevor Sie das Outfit, Ihre Tasche hinzufügen möchten."
                        },
"code":                 {
                        "mes_0": "[Sehen Sie Ihre Tasche] [Zur Kasse]-Taste weiter einkaufen",
                        "mes_1": "[Sehen Sie Ihre Tasche] [Zur Kasse]"                      
                        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in pure JS you are limited to crude branching on `navigator.language`
i do recommend to configure httpd to provide appropriate variant based on `Accept-Language` instead for making it "seamless"